# İf x is diagonalizable then ad(x) is also diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I start to study lie algebras from K. Erdmann, Mark J. Wildon-Introduction to Lie Algebras and I try to solve question below but actually I can't see. How can I start ? Give me a hint please

> Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional complex vector space and let $ L = gl(V)$.
> Suppose that $x \in L$ is diagonalisable, with eigenvalues $λ_1, . . . , λ_n$.
> Show that $\text{ad}(x) \in gl(L)$ is also diagonalisable and that its eigenvalues
> are $λ_i − λ_j$ for $1 ≤ i, j ≤ n$.
> Definition: Let $L$ be a Lie algebra  $\text{ad}(x)$ is a linear map from $L$ to itself defined by $\text{ad}(x)(y)=[x,y]$ :

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take $\mathcal B$ a basis wherein $x$ is diagonalizable and denote $A$ its matrix. Let $B$ the matrix of $y$. $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $\operatorname{ad}(x)$ if

$$AB-BA=\lambda B$$
so using the components we get

$$\lambda_i b_{ij}-b_{ij}\lambda_j=\lambda b_{ij}\implies \lambda=\lambda_i-\lambda_j \quad\text{if}\; b_{ij}\ne0$$
so we see that the matrix $E_{ij}$ with all the entries are $0$ except the $(i,j)$-entry which is equal $1$ is an eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda_i-\lambda_j$ and since $(E_{ij})$ is a basis for $\mathcal M_n(\Bbb R)$ then $\operatorname{ad}(x)$ is diagonalizable.